# Android composable, BasicCodelabTheme shows error

Tags: android, android-theme, composable

I have tried to basic composable codelab exercise. In Android Studio BasicCodelabThemes shows as an error. Please help me to find the error

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContent {
                MyApp {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @Composable
    fun MyApp(content:@Composable () -> Unit) {
        BasicsCodelabTheme {
            Surface(color = Color.Yellow) {
                content()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @Composable
    fun Greeting(name: String) {
        Text(text = "Hello $name!")
    }
```

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: Unresolved reference: BasicsCodelabTheme

Answer (score 0):

Yeah from my research on the BasicCodelabTheme, it is a custom-built composable function, it isn't a predefined one, so you need to create it yourself in your Kotlin file as a composable function for your theme.[BasicCodelabTheme function definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ok1y.png)